# iOS AFNetworking automatically retry request when the internet connection is back

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

Does AFNetworking for iOS offer a solution to cache failed requests (e.g due to no internet connection) and automatically retry the request when the internet connection is back.

Thanks,
Dorin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Network Reachability Manager](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#network-reachability-manager) section of the AFNetworking site. By using "Reachability", your handler will be called whenever the network availability changes. Just set the `setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock` of the `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` (AFNetworking 2) or `AFHTTPSessionManager` (AFNetworking 3):

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

[manager.reachabilityManager setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
    switch (status) {
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
            // do whatever you want when network is available
            break;
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
        default:
            // do whatever you want when network is not available
            break;
    }
}];

[manager.reachabilityManager startMonitoring];
```

Comment: AFNetworking 3.0, `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` is removed.

Comment: Correct, but the syntax is the same for `AFHTTPSessionManager`.

Answer (score 1):

As *matt* said in [AFNetworking issue #393](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/393),AFNetworking doesn't have retry mechanism:

> This is something that a few people have requested, but each each use case had surprisingly different requirements in what the behavior should be, which leads me to believe that a general solution that's useful for all relevant cases is intractable.
>
> I'm of the opinion that request retrying is an application concern (or perhaps even something for the user to initiate); it's not all that difficult to implement yourself:

```
- (void)downloadFileRetryingNumberOfTimes:(NSUInteger)ntimes 
                              success:(void (^)(id responseObject))success 
                              failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure
{
  if (ntimes <= 0) {
    if (failure) {
        NSError *error = ...;
        failure(error);
    }
  } else {
    [self getPath:@"/path/to/file" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if (success) {
            success(...);
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        [self downloadFileRetryingNumberOfTimes:ntimes - 1 success:success failure:failure];
    }];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope, but you can detect in the failure block if the request has timeout. And you can resend it in this case (With like a retry counter of something like this).

Comment: I know the retry counter solution, but I was thinking to a more advanced solution like Parse cloud offers (e.g. saveeventually). In this case I have to implement my own mechanism to store somehow information about failed request and restart them.